# Error in code that I don't know the cause of or how to resolve: AttributeError: 'Embed' object has no attribute 'to_dict' (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

This embed was working a few days ago, I haven't altered it so I don't know why it is suddenly giving me this error, and looking online I haven't found anything that solves my problem.

```
@bot.command(name = 'help')
async def help(ctx):
    helpembed = discord.Embed(title = "Printer Bot", description = "A markov chain bot")
    helpembed.add_field(name = "What does it do?", value = ">markov: wacky sentence generator using machine learning. \n>bfotd: posts a random fact.", inline = True)

   
    await ctx.send(embed=helpembed)
```

If anyone can give some insight, that would be greatly appreciated, as I am quite new to python.
Thanks!

Comment: While you haven't changed the code, did you upgrade the version of the discord library that you are using?

Comment: Not that I can remember, I had to reinstall selfcord a few times as it broke, but I haven't had to upgrade the discord library

Comment: do you have a 
`bot.remove_command('help')` ? because i ran your code and it ran perfectly fine.